# Unable to Mock Optional class of java 8

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am unable to mock the Option class.

My pseudo-code is:

```
PowerMockito.when(stream.findAny()).thenReturn("Mock Of Optional class");
```

But every time I run this code - I am receiving `Optional.empty`.

I am using 1.5 version of PowerMock

Comment: please add your code of unit-test to the question

Comment: Please before asking take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Proper placement of pseudo-code in code brackets, grammar and syntax refactoring.

Comment: FYI -- it's bad practice to mock value objects like `Optional`. Your test is better if you just return a real one; easier to set up and no possibility that you've accidentally mocked it in a way that it can't really behave. Mocking is more appropriate for classes where you can't easily construct a real one that would behave the way you need for a particular test scenario, or if you want to test that your code calls another object's methods for side effects without actually running the side effects.

Answer (score 20):

There is no need to mock primitive classes like `Future` and `Optional`. Just wrap the mocked data you want to return inside a real `Optional`:

```
MyData myData = Mockito.mock(MyData.class)
when(repository.getData()).thenReturn(Optional.of(myData));
```

For mocking absence:

```
when(repository.getData()).thenReturn(Optional.<MyData>empty());
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot mock a final class in version 1 of mockito and Optional is a final class.

```
public final class Optional<T> {
```

In version 2 of mockito you can do this.